# Snake game stops after I reach 18 points. Why?

Tags: c++

Okay so this is some very basic code for a classic snake game that I wrote. I need it as a part of a bigger project I'm working on but while testing I ran into this very annoying error. If someone could just execute it and tell me what I'm missing, that'd be great. Any extra suggestions are also welcome. I've attached the code below and written some very basic comments, hope that they are enough to understand it.

The Error: My code stops after the player achieves 18 points. To be very specific, No more fruits appear on the console at score = 18.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<utility>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

bool play = true;
int score = 0;

class Arena
{
    private: 

    int length, w, h, size, fx, fy;
    char snakerep, fruitrep, dir;
    queue<pair<int,int>> snakey, marker;
    vector<vector<char>> arena;

    public:

    Arena()
    {
        //snake stuff
        length = 1;
        snakerep = 'O';
        for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
            snakey.push({1, i+1});
        dir = 'R';
        
        //arena stuff
        size = 25;
        h = size, w = 2*size;
        arena.resize(h, vector<char>(w, ' '));
        
        //fruit stuff
        fruitrep = 'F';
        fx = 1 + (rand() % h);
        fy = 1 + (rand() % w);
        arena[fx][fy] = fruitrep;
    }

    void setFruit()
    {
        fx = 1 + (rand() % h);
        fy = 1 + (rand() % w);
        
        arena[fx][fy] = fruitrep;
    }
    
    void setArena()
    {
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < w ; i++)
        {
            arena[0][i] = '*';
            arena[h-1][i] = '*';
        }

        for(int i = 1 ; i < h-1 ; i++)
        {
            arena[i][0] = '*';
            arena[i][w-1] = '*';
        }

        for(int i = 1 ; i < h-1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < w-1 ; j++)
            {
                arena[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }

        arena[fx][fy] = fruitrep;
    }

    void setSnake()
    {
        queue<pair<int,int>> temp_snakey = snakey;
        
        while(!temp_snakey.empty())
        {

            pair<int, int> xy = temp_snakey.front();
            temp_snakey.pop();

            int x = xy.first, y = xy.second;

            //condition for hitting any of the boundaries
            if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || x >= size-1 || y >= 2*size-1)
                play = false;

            //condition for hitting itself
            if (arena[x][y] == snakerep)
                play = false;

            //condition for if a fruit is eaten
            if (arena[x][y] == fruitrep)
            {
                setFruit();
                //increase length of the snake 
                length++, score++;
                marker.push({x,y});
            }

            arena[x][y] = snakerep;
        }
    }

    void moveSnake(char dir)
    {
        //calculate the new location of the head or whatever according to the direction given within the brackets
        pair<int,int> prevHead = snakey.back(), newHead;

        if (dir == 'R')
            newHead = {prevHead.first, prevHead.second+1};
        else if (dir == 'L')
            newHead = {prevHead.first, prevHead.second-1};
        else if (dir == 'U')
            newHead = {prevHead.first-1, prevHead.second}; 
        else if (dir == 'D')
            newHead = {prevHead.first+1, prevHead.second};

        //pop the tail from the queue and add the new head
        pair<int, int> tail = snakey.front();
        if (!marker.empty() && tail == marker.front())
            marker.pop();
        else
            snakey.pop();
        
        snakey.push(newHead);
    }

    void printAll()
    {
        //prints the matrix
        for(int i = 0 ; i < h ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < w ; j++)
            {
                cout<<arena[i][j];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

    void getDirection()
    {
        if(_kbhit())
        {
            char ch = _getch();
            if (dir == 'R' || dir == 'L')
            {
                if (ch == 'w')
                    dir = 'U'; 
                else if (ch == 's')
                    dir = 'D';
                else if (ch == 'x')
                    play = false;
            }   
            else if (dir == 'U' || dir == 'D')
            {
                if (ch == 'd')
                    dir = 'R'; 
                else if (ch == 'a')
                    dir = 'L';
                else if (ch == 'x')
                    play = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void playGame()
    {
        getDirection();
        setArena();
        moveSnake(dir);
        setSnake();
        printAll();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Arena A;

    while(play)
    {
        A.playGame();
        cout<<" SCORE = "<<score<<endl;
        //better than using system("cls"), because it moves cursor to beginning of console, flickering stops
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {0, 0});
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to use your debugger to see what happens when you reach 18.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre].

Comment: `setfruit` does not check if the tile where the fruit is placed is empty. When there was already a fruit before, then no new fruit is added. Are you sure the issue happens always at a score of 18?

Comment: hm.. there is only 1 fruit at the same time present? Still, in `setSnake` you first call `setfruit` then `arena[x][y] = snakerep;`. If the random coordinates are that `x` and `y` then no fruit will appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 18th fruit is getting generated out of bounds. Your random location function is incorrect. You have

```
void setFruit()
{
    fx = 1 + (rand() % h);
    fy = 1 + (rand() % w);
    
    arena[fx][fy] = fruitrep;
}
```

Okay, consider `fx`, `rand() % h` will give you a number in [0 .. h-1] inclusive but you are adding one to it because the zeroth position is a wall. So now you have [1..h] but `h` is out of bounds. Also there is a wall on the right too. So putting that all together, I think what you want is

```
void setFruit()
{
    fx = 1 + (rand() % (h-2));
    fy = 1 + (rand() % (w-2));
    
    arena[fx][fy] = fruitrep;
}
```

Also you should change the Arena constructor to use this function. It is good to not repeat bits of code like that.